# cpp: upcast shared_ptr problem(C2440) with class

Tags: c++

First, Sorry for my poor english.
upcast with struct is compiled well

```
struct FTestBase
{
public:
    FTestBase() {}
};

struct FTestDerived : FTestBase
{
public:
    FTestDerived() {}
};

std::shared_ptr<FTestBase> tmp = std::make_shared<FTestDerived>();//good
```

but upcast with class is failed.

```
class FTestBase
{
public:
    FTestBase() {}
};

class FTestDerived : FTestBase
{
public:
    FTestDerived() {}
};

std::shared_ptr<FTestBase> tmp = std::make_shared<FTestDerived>(); //C2440
```

c2440 'initializing' cannot convert from 'std::shared_ptr' to 'std::shared_ptr.

why? How can I upcast shared_ptr with class?

Comment: What is the actual error? Do you understand that `struct` defaults to `public` and `class` to `private`?

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: The second answer of the dupe I linked seems more appropriate than the first one since your issue is related to `public` vs `private` inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Structs in C++ are just classes with default public accessibility and *inheritance*.

`struct FTestDerived : FTestBase` allows `FTestDerived` to be seen as a child of `FTestBase`. However, with classes, inheritance is private by default rather than public by default as with structs, so `class FTestDerived : FTestBase` does not expose `FTestBase` as a parent.

You're looking for:

```cpp
class FTestDerived : public FTestBase
{
public:
    FTestDerived() {}
};
```